# BLE SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED (error code 1) only on some devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing a BLE scanner that scans for peripherals, connects, and disconnects every so often.

I'm "cycling" the scanning - turning it off for 2 seconds and then turning it back on for 10 - because I read somewhere (will try to find reference) that otherwise (post Android 7.0) the OS will stop scanning in the background after 30 minutes or so. I also experienced something to that effect.

The problem is, on some devices (for example, Motorola Moto Z & Google Pixel), I'm getting an error [SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html#SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED) indicating that this app has already started a scan with these parameters.

But, with my scanning algorithm, I enforce that `stopScan` is called **necessarily** before startScan is attempted. Here's a relevant code sample that produces the error on the devices mentioned. It's ONLY the scanning part of the code.

```
private final int SCANNER_DOWN_TIME = 2000;
private final int SCANNER_LIFETIME_MS = 10000;

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        private BluetoothLeScanner scanner;

        final ScanSettings.Builder builder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
        final ScanSettings settings = builder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();

        public void run() {
            try {
                bootScanner();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Sentry.capture(e);
            }
        }

        class StartScannerAndScheduleReboot implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                    if (scanner != null) {
                        scanner.startScan(null, settings, sensorReadingHandler);
                    }
                } else {
                    bluetoothAdapter.enable();
                }

                bootScanHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                bootScan = new RebootScanner();
                bootScanHandler.postDelayed(bootScan, SCANNER_LIFETIME_MS);
            }
        }

        class RebootScanner implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bootScanner();
            }
        }

        private void bootScanner() {
            try {
                scanner.stopScan(sensorReadingHandler);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* We can ignore this - there are cases that this will happen & it's ok */
            }

            startScanHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            startScan = new StartScannerAndScheduleReboot();
            startScanHandler.postDelayed(startScan, SCANNER_DOWN_TIME);
        }

        private ScanCallback sensorReadingHandler = new ScanCallback() 

{ /* I don't believe the scanCallback code is relevant, as this happens before any connections are even attempted. */ }

        };
```

Not surprisingly, the app is still able to read BLE transmissions, but some are dropped. This leads me to believe that I shouldn't just ignore this error.

Comment: Did you find a solution?